# read words from file, line by line and concatenate to paragraph

Tags: python

I have a really long list of words that are on each line. How do I make a program that takes in all that and print them all side by side?

I tried making the word an element of a list, but I don't know how to proceed.

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
def convert(lst):
    return([i for item in lst for i in item.split()])

lst = [''' -The list of words come here- ''']

print(convert(lst))
```

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: If you have them in a list, [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) into a string: `' '.join(list_of_words)`

Comment: @TheFool yes I managed to put them into a list

Comment: Its a good idea to post the code you already have. So that people can help you to build onto it.

Comment: aight I edited it

Comment: You are missing one closing bracket in your print statement. If you happen to have any errors, you can add them to the post too, it will be helpful. Or otherwise, add what is the current output and how its different from what you like.

Comment: what would I have to add if I want to randomly delete "n" number of words and jumble the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the words in a list, you can use the `join()` function to concatenate them. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

```py
words = open('your_file.txt').readlines()
separator = ' '
print(separator.join(words))
```

Another, a little bit more cumbersome method would be to print the words using the builtin `print()` function but suppress the newline that `print()` normally adds automatically to the end of your argument.

```
words = open('your_file.txt').readlines()
for word in words:
  print(word, end=' ')
```

Comment: one problem though, the list of words are not in a text file. I have them copied and just pasted them into the programme. So i should probable make a text file and dump those words in, then use this into the programme right?

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution. Otherwise, you would have to paste them into your program and make it a valid list, therefore you have to add quotes around each word (and brackets at the front and end) which can be become really time consuming if have a lot of words.

Comment: what would I have to add if I want to randomly delete "n" number of words and jumble the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and example.txt just has a list of words going down line by line.

```
with open("example.txt", "r") as a_file:
    sentence = ""
    for line in a_file:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        sentence = sentence + f"{stripped_line} "
print(sentence)
```

Comment: That or if it's not in a text file just add all the words into a text file and it will work, make sure that it matches what ever the name of the file it's opening line "example.txt"

Comment: what would I have to add if I want to randomly delete "n" number of words and jumble the rest?

Comment: You mean just remove words at random? Like example you want to remove 8 words, it will delete eight random words? And then "jumble" you mean pick words randomly not going down the list?

Comment: Yes remove 8 words (let’s say), and jumble the words

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is really large and you cant fit it all in memory, you can read the words lazy and write them to disk instead of holding the whole output in memory.

```py
# create a generator that yields each individual line
lines = (l for l in open('words'))

with open("output", "w+") as writer:
  # read the file line by line to avoid memory issues
  while True:
    try:
      line = next(lines)
      # add to the paragraph in the out file
      writer.write(line.replace('\n', ' '))
    except StopIteration:
      break
```

You can check the working example here: https://replit.com/@bluebrown/readwritewords#main.py

Comment: what would I have to add if I want to randomly delete "n" number of words and jumble the rest?

Comment: You could count the line numbers in the loop here. And then you say, oh its line 5, I skip this one.

Comment: You could also match the line with regex and write only if you like the word etc.  Or even transform the words. Possibilities are endless. Just write conditionally, so it will skip the lines.

Comment: Sorry mate, you need to go back to the basics and learn about the primitves of the langauge first it seems.

Comment: fair enough, literally just started programming